# Segmentation fault for STOSB in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I am trying to write a subroutine that takes in a string, looks at each letter, and replaces lowercase vowels with uppercase vowels. I am using raspberry pi desktop (x86) on a VM with NASM. Here is part of my code:

```
again:
lodsb ; load next byte into AL and increment EIP
cmp AL, 0 ; check for end
jz quitloop ; exit if end
cmp AL, 'a' ; check if char is a
jnz next1 ; jump to next test if not a
dec ESI ; move back to address of character
mov AL, 'A' ; replace character
stosb ; store character
jmp again ; restart loop with next char
```

"next1" checks for 'e' and on until y. From what I can tell, lodsb seems to be working because for a string starting with "the" it loops through all tests twice then gets a segmentation error in test1 (checking the e). The documentation I can find on STOSB is not that helpful; it says I can use parameters but not how to do so. (If I try to put registers as parameters, it doesn't assemble because of operand/operator error.)

Comment: Hey Fuz, I'm sorry I didn't know that I should. This is my first time posting for answers anywhere (in my second CS course ever), I didn't know how long either place would take so I cast a wide net. I came here to delete this question after you helped me fix it on my reddit post, but found that I couldn't because it had been answered here too. Now I know for next time that if I crosspost, I will link.

Comment: No problem.  Just remember to link cross posts so nobody has to repeat work done on other posts.   As for deleting, don't do that either.  Deleting your post erases the work you put into writing it, which is not a nice thing to do.

Comment: If you don't know debugging, now is a good time to learn it.  Debugging assembly is the same as with other languages: single step each line and verify program state in between steps, also, verify that the next line is the appropriate one.  If you find something unexpected, then focus there.  If you single stepped this, you could have noticed that one of the pointers doesn't advance and so goes out of step with the other.

Comment: Intel's and AMD's manuals are pretty decent for the exact details of what an instruction can do: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lods:lodsb:lodsw:lodsd:lodsq is from scraped from Intel's PDFs.  See the original SDM if you don't understand some of the notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> lodsb ; load next byte into AL and increment **EIP**

It's not fruitful to state that this instruction increments EIP. Every instruction has an effect on EIP. Maybe you meant to say that `lodsb` increments ESI?

---

Seeing that `dec ESI` instruction, I assume that you're working in 32-bit mode where `DS` would normally be equal to `ES`.

The `lodsb` string primitive works from `DS:ESI` and `stosb` works from `ES:EDI`.

If your intention is to capitalize in-place, then the simple solution is to write the capital vowel at the address right before where ESI is pointing to:

```
again:
lodsb                   ; load next byte into AL and increment EIP
cmp AL, 0               ; check for end
jz quitloop             ; exit if end
cmp AL, 'a'             ; check if char is a
jnz next1               ; jump to next test if not a

mov byte [ESI - 1], 'A' ; replace character

jmp again               ; restart loop with next char
```

Please notice that the `dec ESI` instruction together with not effectively changing the small character, provoked an endless loop!
And because the `stosb` instruction happily ran along, at some point EDI will have triggered a segmentation fault.